# openui5 ActionSelect not showing ListItems in drop list

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use the sap.m.ActionSelect within my application (as I like the combination of selection and action buttons). However, even within this simple test, I cannot get the drop list to show anything other than the first item. I am sure I am doing something completely dumb, but this one has me beaten. If anyone can spot the deliberate mistake I would be grateful!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ActionSelect</title>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="../openui5/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.unified" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sparqlish":"../",
                "sparqlish":"../sparqlish",
         "Components":"../",
                "Components":"../Components"
    }'
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.ActionSelect");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.Button");
this.oServiceSelect = new sap.m.ActionSelect();
var oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Country1");
oItem.setText("Canada");
this.oServiceSelect.addItem(oItem);
oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Country2");
oItem.setText("Deutschland");
this.oServiceSelect.addItem(oItem);
oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Country3");
oItem.setText("England");
this.oServiceSelect.addItem(oItem);
oItem = new sap.ui.core.ListItem("Country4");
oItem.setText("Россия");
this.oServiceSelect.addItem(oItem);
this.oServiceSelect.setEnabled(true);
this.oServiceSelect.placeAt("serviceMenu");
this.oServiceSelect.addButton(new sap.m.Button({
    text : "Action 1",
    press : function(){alert("Action 1")}
}));
this.oServiceSelect.addButton(new sap.m.Button({
    text : "Action 2",
    press : function(){alert("Action 2")}
}));

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="serviceMenu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues in the code. First, you are loading the libs at bootstrap with three different attributes. This is wrong! Instead simply use one attribute and list the libs you want separated by comma.

Another issue in the code is that you are loading both sap.ui.commons and sap.m. As a rule of thumb [you should never ever mix sap.ui.commons and sap.m](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820.html)!!! That's very important.

In your case you could and definitely should even completely remove sap.ui.commons because as far as I can see it from your code you are not using it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think my root problem was the three data-sap-ui-libs attributes, because when I combine them the order of declaration has no impact. With regard to the use of sap.ui.commons, this was an example extracted from something more complex although I will take you advice and not mix them

Answer (score -3):

It appears that the order in which one declares the data-sap-ui-libs is important. The original order in the example above was:

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons" 
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.unified"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
```

However if I reorder these to the following, with data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" everything works well

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.unified"
```